# Is it possible to find a null vector of matrix $A$ of size $m\times n$ when $m >> n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to find a null vector (or null space) of matrix $A$ of size $m\times n$ when $m >> n$? or is it the case that in such a case, the null space does not exist?

Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean by $m >>n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for an $m \times n$ matrix to have a nontrivial nullspace even when $m \gg n$. For instance, the $m \times 2$ matrix: $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 3 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ m & m\end{bmatrix}$$ has $v = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$ in its nullspace for any integer $m \ge 1$.

Note that the nullspace of a matrix always exists and is non-empty because the vector of all zeros lies in the nullspace. However, there are non-zero vectors in the nullspace if and only if the rank of the matrix does NOT equal the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

An $m\times n$ matrix is a linear transformation form ${\mathbb R}^n$ to ${\mathbb R}^m$:

- the columns span the image; and
- the null space is the orthogonal complement of the row space.

If the row space has dimension less than $n$,  then the null-space is nontrivial.